# How to find the amount of p1,p2,p3,p4 and p5 based on the pf column give?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

```
std_vol = m_vol.agg(["std"]) 


#Using q.cut to segreate stocks into portfolio

portfolio_id = std_vol.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, bins, labels=["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"]), 
axis=1)
display(portfolio_id)
```

Can I use a for-loop for it?

current output:
[image: current output]

desire output:

```
p1 = s_0001, s_0004,s_0005.... 

p2 = s_0006, s_0008, s_0009...
```

Comment: This looks like Pandas, could you please [edit] to clarify and perhaps tag?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) The examples of desired output don't seem to correspond with what's in the image.